# Normal Mapping and keep the tangents

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, graphics, glsl

Let's say you have a 3D mesh with normal map provided with. The mesh owns as well tangents, bitangents and normals.

From the tangents, bitangents and normals, you could build the TBN matrix that is a matrix that transform tangent space to world space. That way, to get the *real* normal you just have to do something like that :

```
mat3 TBN = mat3(tangent, bitangent, normal);
vec3 realNormal = TBN * normalFromTheNormalMap;
```

However, how to get the *real* tangent and bitangent from this system?

Comment: [Gram–Schmidt Orthonormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) `t = normalize(tangent - realNormal  * dot(tangent, realNormal));`

Comment: that was obvious... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [Orthogonalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality) the vectors. A common way for the [Orthogonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonalization) is the [Gram–Schmidt Orthonormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

This algorithm uses the circumstance that, the *dot* product of 2 vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (length) of both vectors.

```
dot( N, T ) == length( N ) * length( T ) * cos( angle_N_T )
```

This follows, that the *dot* product of 2 unit vectors (normalized vectors) is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors, because the length of a unit vector is 1.

```
uN = normalize( A )
uT = normalize( B )
cos( angle_T_N ) == dot( uT, uN )
```

[image]

If `realNormal` is a normalized vector (its length is 1) and `tangent` and `binormal` are orthogonal, then the `realTangent` and the the `realBinormal` can be calculated like this:

```
realTangent  = normalize( tangent - realNormal * dot(tangent,  realNormal) );
realBinormal = binormal - realNormal * dot(binormal, realNormal);
realBinormal = normalize( realBinormal - realTangent * dot(realBinormal, realTangent) );
```

If `tangent` and `binormal` are normalized vectors too, then the `normalize` function can be substituted by dividing with the dot product of the source vector and the *real* vector:

```
realTangent   = tangent - realNormal * dot(tangent,  realNormal);
realTangent  /= dot(tangent, realTangent);
realBinormal  = binormal - realNormal * dot(binormal, realNormal);
realBinormal  = realBinormal - realTangent * dot(realBinormal, realTangent);
realBinormal /= dot(binormal, realBinormal);
```

See further [How to calculate Tangent and Binormal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255806/how-to-calculate-tangent-and-binormal/44901073#44901073).

Comment: You do not need to project the binormal on the realTangent also? Because in the graham schmidt process, you need to project (n - 1) times for the nth vector

Comment: A last question, is it the same if I compute the bi normal BEFORE the tangent, or is it not the same?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier You can change the order, but it is not exactly the same if you do `realBinormal  = realBinormal - realTangent * dot(realBinormal, realTangent);` in compare to `realTangent  = realTangent - realBinormal * dot(realBinormal, realTangent);`. Both will give orthogonal vectors, but slightly different.