# Bump Mapping with javascript and glsl

Tags: javascript, glsl, shader, bump-mapping

```js
 /**
         * A class creating buffers for a textured box to render it with WebGL
         */
        class RasterTextureBox {
            /**
             * Creates all WebGL buffers for the textured box
             *     6 ------- 7
             *    / |       / |
             *   3 ------- 2  |
             *   |  |      |  |
             *   |  5 -----|- 4
             *   | /       | /
             *   0 ------- 1
             *  looking in negative z axis direction
             * @param {WebGLContext} gl - The canvas' context
             * @param {Vector} minPoint - The minimal x,y,z of the box
             * @param {Vector} maxPoint - The maximal x,y,z of the box
             */
            constructor(gl, minPoint, maxPoint, texture) {
                this.gl = gl;
                const mi = minPoint;
                const ma = maxPoint;
                let vertices = [
                    // front
                    mi.x, mi.y, ma.z, ma.x, mi.y, ma.z, ma.x, ma.y, ma.z,
                    ma.x, ma.y, ma.z, mi.x, ma.y, ma.z, mi.x, mi.y, ma.z,
                    // back
                    ma.x, mi.y, mi.z, mi.x, mi.y, mi.z, mi.x, ma.y, mi.z,
                    mi.x, ma.y, mi.z, ma.x, ma.y, mi.z, ma.x, mi.y, mi.z,
                    // right
                    ma.x, mi.y, ma.z, ma.x, mi.y, mi.z, ma.x, ma.y, mi.z,
                    ma.x, ma.y, mi.z, ma.x, ma.y, ma.z, ma.x, mi.y, ma.z,
                    // top
                    mi.x, ma.y, ma.z, ma.x, ma.y, ma.z, ma.x, ma.y, mi.z,
                    ma.x, ma.y, mi.z, mi.x, ma.y, mi.z, mi.x, ma.y, ma.z,
                    // left
                    mi.x, mi.y, mi.z, mi.x, mi.y, ma.z, mi.x, ma.y, ma.z,
                    mi.x, ma.y, ma.z, mi.x, ma.y, mi.z, mi.x, mi.y, mi.z,
                    // bottom
                    mi.x, mi.y, mi.z, ma.x, mi.y, mi.z, ma.x, mi.y, ma.z,
                    ma.x, mi.y, ma.z, mi.x, mi.y, ma.z, mi.x, mi.y, mi.z
                ];
    
                const vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                this.vertexBuffer = vertexBuffer;
                this.elements = vertices.length / 3;
    
                let cubeTexture = gl.createTexture();
                let cubeImage = new Image();
                cubeImage.onload = function () {
                    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, cubeTexture);
                    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, cubeImage);
                    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
                    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
                    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
                }
                cubeImage.src = texture;
                this.texBuffer = cubeTexture;
    
                let uv = [
                    // front
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                    // back
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                    // right
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                    // top
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                    // left
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                    // bottom
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
                    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
                ];
                let uvBuffer = this.gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer);
                gl.bufferData(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(uv),
                    gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                this.texCoords = uvBuffer;
            }
    
            render(shader) {
                this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
                const positionLocation = shader.getAttributeLocation("a_position");
                this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
                this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
                // Bind the texture coordinates in this.texCoords
                // to their attribute in the shader
               
                this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.texCoords);
                const texCoordLocation = shader.getAttributeLocation("a_texCoord");
                this.gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
                this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(texCoordLocation, 2, this.gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
                this.gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
                this.gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.texBuffer);
                shader.getUniformInt("sampler").set(0);
                this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.elements);
    
                this.gl.disableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    
                //disable texture vertex attrib array
                this.gl.disableVertexAttribArray(texCoordLocation);
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Class representing a 4x4 Matrix
         */
        class Matrix {
         
          constructor(mat) {
            this.data = new Float32Array(16);
            for (let row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
              for (let col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                this.data[row * 4 + col] = mat[col * 4 + row];
              }
            }
          }
        
          getVal(row, col) {
            return this.data[col * 4 + row];
          }
       
          setVal(row, col, val) {
            this.data[col * 4 + row] = val;
          }
        
          static translation(translation) {
        
            let m = Matrix.identity();
            m.setVal(0, 3, translation.x);
            m.setVal(1, 3, translation.y);
            m.setVal(2, 3, translation.z);
            return m;
          }
        
          static rotation(axis, angle) {
        
            let m = Matrix.identity()
            let sin = Math.sin(angle);
            let cos = Math.cos(angle);
            if (axis.x != 0) {
              m.setVal(1, 1, cos);
              m.setVal(1, 2, -sin);
              m.setVal(2, 1, sin);
              m.setVal(2, 2, cos);
            } else if (axis.y != 0) {
              m.setVal(0, 0, cos);
              m.setVal(0, 2, sin);
              m.setVal(2, 0, -sin);
              m.setVal(2, 2, cos);
            } else {
              m.setVal(0, 0, cos);
              m.setVal(0, 1, -sin);
              m.setVal(1, 0, sin);
              m.setVal(1, 1, cos);
            }
            return m;
          }
        
          static scaling(scale) {
        
            let m = Matrix.identity();
            m.setVal(0, 0, scale.x);
            m.setVal(1, 1, scale.y);
            m.setVal(2, 2, scale.z);
            return m;
          }
        
          /**
           * Constructs a lookat matrix
           * @param  {Vector} eye    - The position of the viewer
           * @param  {Vector} center - The position to look at
           * @param  {Vector} up     - The up direction
           * @return {Matrix}          The resulting lookat matrix
           */
          static lookat(eye, center, up) {
        
            let fBig = center.sub(eye);
        
            // Vom Eye zum Center Punkt
            let f = fBig.normalised();
        
            // UP-Vektor
            let upNorm = up.normalised();
        
            // Kreuzprodukt
            let s = f.cross(upNorm);
        
            let u = s.normalised().cross(f);
        
            // s, u und f sind die Vektoren des Kamerakoordinatensystems
        
            // Lookat Matrix, 3x3 betrifft Rotation und Skalierung
            let mat = new Matrix([
              s.x, s.y, s.z, 0,
              u.x, u.y, u.z, 0, -f.x, -f.y, -f.z, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 1
            ]);
        
            // Noch weitere Berechnungen? Translation
            let trans = Matrix.translation(eye.mul(-1));
            mat = mat.mul(trans);
            return mat;
        
          }
        
         static frustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far) {
            // TODO [exercise 9]
            const n2 = 2 * near;    
            const rpl = right + left;    
            const rml = right - left;    
            const tpb = top + bottom;    
            const tmb = top - bottom;    
            const fpn = far + near;    
            const fmn = far - near;    
            const n2f = n2 * far;    
            return new Matrix([
                n2 / rml, 0, rpl / rml, 0,
                0, n2 / tmb, tpb / tmb, 0,
                0, 0, -fpn / fmn, -n2f / fmn,
                0, 0, -1, 0
             ]);
        
        
          }
        
          static perspective(fovy, aspect, near, far) {
        
            // frustum Methode verwenden. Foliensatz 10
        
            const top = near * Math.tan((Math.PI / 180) * (fovy / 2));    
            const bottom = -top;    
            const right = top * aspect;    
            const left = -right;
                
            return Matrix.frustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
        
          }
        
          /**
           * Returns the identity matrix
           */
          static identity() {
            return new Matrix([
              1, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 1, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 1, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 1
            ]);
          }
    
        mul(other) {
        
            if (other instanceof Matrix) {
              // [exercise 7]
              let m = Matrix.identity();
              for (let row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
                for (let col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                  let sum = 0;
                  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    sum += this.getVal(row, i) * other.getVal(i, col);
                  }
                  m.setVal(row, col, sum);
                }
              }
              return m;
            } else {
              let v = [0, 0, 0, 0];
              for (let row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                  v[row] += this.getVal(row, i) * other.valueOf()[i];
                }
              }
              return new Vector(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]);
            }
        
          }
        
        
          transpose() {
            let m = Matrix.identity();
            for (let row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
              for (let col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
                m.setVal(row, col, this.getVal(col, row));
              }
            }
            return m;
        
          }
        
         
          invert() {
            let mat = this.data;
            let dst = new Float32Array(16); //ret.getValues();
            let tmp = new Float32Array(12);
        
            /* temparray for pairs */
            let src = new Float32Array(16); //new float[16];
        
            /* array of transpose source matrix */
            let det;
        
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
              src[i] = mat[i * 4];
              src[i + 4] = mat[i * 4 + 1];
              src[i + 8] = mat[i * 4 + 2];
              src[i + 12] = mat[i * 4 + 3];
            }
        
           tmp[0] = src[10] * src[15];
            tmp[1] = src[11] * src[14];
            tmp[2] = src[9] * src[15];
            tmp[3] = src[11] * src[13];
            tmp[4] = src[9] * src[14];
            tmp[5] = src[10] * src[13];
            tmp[6] = src[8] * src[15];
            tmp[7] = src[11] * src[12];
            tmp[8] = src[8] * src[14];
            tmp[9] = src[10] * src[12];
            tmp[10] = src[8] * src[13];
            tmp[11] = src[9] * src[12];
        
            dst[0] = tmp[0] * src[5] + tmp[3] * src[6] + tmp[4] * src[7];
            dst[0] -= tmp[1] * src[5] + tmp[2] * src[6] + tmp[5] * src[7];
            dst[1] = tmp[1] * src[4] + tmp[6] * src[6] + tmp[9] * src[7];
            dst[1] -= tmp[0] * src[4] + tmp[7] * src[6] + tmp[8] * src[7];
            dst[2] = tmp[2] * src[4] + tmp[7] * src[5] + tmp[10] * src[7];
            dst[2] -= tmp[3] * src[4] + tmp[6] * src[5] + tmp[11] * src[7];
            dst[3] = tmp[5] * src[4] + tmp[8] * src[5] + tmp[11] * src[6];
            dst[3] -= tmp[4] * src[4] + tmp[9] * src[5] + tmp[10] * src[6];
            dst[4] = tmp[1] * src[1] + tmp[2] * src[2] + tmp[5] * src[3];
            dst[4] -= tmp[0] * src[1] + tmp[3] * src[2] + tmp[4] * src[3];
            dst[5] = tmp[0] * src[0] + tmp[7] * src[2] + tmp[8] * src[3];
            dst[5] -= tmp[1] * src[0] + tmp[6] * src[2] + tmp[9] * src[3];
            dst[6] = tmp[3] * src[0] + tmp[6] * src[1] + tmp[11] * src[3];
            dst[6] -= tmp[2] * src[0] + tmp[7] * src[1] + tmp[10] * src[3];
            dst[7] = tmp[4] * src[0] + tmp[9] * src[1] + tmp[10] * src[2];
            dst[7] -= tmp[5] * src[0] + tmp[8] * src[1] + tmp[11] * src[2];
        
            tmp[0] = src[2] * src[7];
            tmp[1] = src[3] * src[6];
            tmp[2] = src[1] * src[7];
            tmp[3] = src[3] * src[5];
            tmp[4] = src[1] * src[6];
            tmp[5] = src[2] * src[5];
            tmp[6] = src[0] * src[7];
            tmp[7] = src[3] * src[4];
            tmp[8] = src[0] * src[6];
            tmp[9] = src[2] * src[4];
            tmp[10] = src[0] * src[5];
            tmp[11] = src[1] * src[4];
        
           dst[8] = tmp[0] * src[13] + tmp[3] * src[14] + tmp[4] * src[15];
            dst[8] -= tmp[1] * src[13] + tmp[2] * src[14] + tmp[5] * src[15];
            dst[9] = tmp[1] * src[12] + tmp[6] * src[14] + tmp[9] * src[15];
            dst[9] -= tmp[0] * src[12] + tmp[7] * src[14] + tmp[8] * src[15];
            dst[10] = tmp[2] * src[12] + tmp[7] * src[13] + tmp[10] * src[15];
            dst[10] -= tmp[3] * src[12] + tmp[6] * src[13] + tmp[11] * src[15];
            dst[11] = tmp[5] * src[12] + tmp[8] * src[13] + tmp[11] * src[14];
            dst[11] -= tmp[4] * src[12] + tmp[9] * src[13] + tmp[10] * src[14];
            dst[12] = tmp[2] * src[10] + tmp[5] * src[11] + tmp[1] * src[9];
            dst[12] -= tmp[4] * src[11] + tmp[0] * src[9] + tmp[3] * src[10];
            dst[13] = tmp[8] * src[11] + tmp[0] * src[8] + tmp[7] * src[10];
            dst[13] -= tmp[6] * src[10] + tmp[9] * src[11] + tmp[1] * src[8];
            dst[14] = tmp[6] * src[9] + tmp[11] * src[11] + tmp[3] * src[8];
            dst[14] -= tmp[10] * src[11] + tmp[2] * src[8] + tmp[7] * src[9];
            dst[15] = tmp[10] * src[10] + tmp[4] * src[8] + tmp[9] * src[9];
            dst[15] -= tmp[8] * src[9] + tmp[11] * src[10] + tmp[5] * src[8];
        
            det = src[0] * dst[0] + src[1] * dst[1] + src[2] * dst[2] + src[3] * dst[3];
        
            if (det == 0.0) {
              throw new Error("singular matrix is not invertible");
            }
        
            /* calculate matrix inverse */
            det = 1 / det;
        
            for (let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
              dst[j] *= det;
            }
        
            let ret = Matrix.identity();
            ret.data = dst;
            return ret;
          }
        }
        
        /**
         * Class representing a vector in 4D space
         */
        class Vector {
        
            /**
             * Create a vector
             * @param  {number} x - The x component
             * @param  {number} y - The y component
             * @param  {number} z - The z component
             * @param  {number} w - The w component
             * @return {number}     The resulting vector
             */
            constructor(x, y, z, w) {
                this.data = [x, y, z, w];
            }
        
            //has getter and setter
        
            add(other) {
                return new Vector(
                    this.x + other.x,
                    this.y + other.y,
                    this.z + other.z,
                    this.w + other.w
                );
            }
        
            sub(other) {
                return new Vector(
                    this.x - other.x,
                    this.y - other.y,
                    this.z - other.z,
                    this.w - other.w
                );
            }
        
            mul(other) {
                return new Vector(
                    this.x * other,
                    this.y * other,
                    this.z * other,
                    this.w
                );
            }
        
            div(other) {
                return new Vector(
                    this.x / other,
                    this.y / other,
                    this.z / other,
                    this.w
                );
            }
        
            dot(other) {
                if (other instanceof Vector) {
                    return this.x * other.x + this.y * other.y + this.z * other.z;
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Dot product only works with vectors!");
                }
            }
        
            cross(other) {
                if (other instanceof Vector) {
                    return new Vector(
                        this.y * other.z - this.z * other.y,
                        this.z * other.x - this.x * other.z,
                        this.x * other.y - this.y * other.x,
                        0
                    );
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Dot product only works with vectors!");
                }
            }
        
            valueOf() {
                return this.data;
            }
        
            normalised() {
                const l = this.length;
                return this.div(l);
            }
        
            equals(other) {
                return (
                    Math.abs(this.x - other.x) <= Number.EPSILON &&
                    Math.abs(this.y - other.y) <= Number.EPSILON &&
                    Math.abs(this.z - other.z) <= Number.EPSILON &&
                    ((!this.w && !other.w) || Math.abs(this.w - other.w) <= Number.EPSILON)
                );
            }
        
            get length() {
                return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y + this.z * this.z);
            }
        }
        
        /**
         * Class representing a Node in a Scenegraph
         */
        class Node {
          /**
           * Accepts a visitor according to the visitor pattern
           * @param  {Visitor} visitor - The visitor
           */
          accept(visitor) { }
        }
        
        /**
         * Class representing a GroupNode in the Scenegraph.
         * A GroupNode holds a transformation and is able
         * to have child nodes attached to it.
         * @extends Node
         */
        class GroupNode extends Node {
          /**
           * Constructor
           * @param  {Matrix} mat - A matrix describing the node's transformation
           */
          constructor(mat) {
            super();
            this.matrix = mat;
            // TODO [exercise 8]
            this.children = [];
          }
        
          /**
           * Accepts a visitor according to the visitor pattern
           * @param  {Visitor} visitor - The visitor
           */
          accept(visitor) {
            // TODO [exercise 8]
            visitor.visitGroupNode(this);
          }
        
          /**
           * Adds a child node
           * @param {Node} childNode - The child node to add
           */
          add(childNode) {
            // TODO [exercise 8]
            this.children.push(childNode);
          }
        }
        
        /**
         * Class representing a Textured Axis Aligned Box in the Scenegraph
         * @extends Node
         */
        class TextureBoxNode extends Node {
          
          constructor(minPoint, maxPoint, texture) {
            super();
            this.minPoint = minPoint;
            this.maxPoint = maxPoint;
            this.texture = texture;
          }
        
          accept(visitor) {
            // TODO [exercise 8]
            visitor.visitTextureBoxNode(this);
          }
        }
```

```css
//Texture Fragment Shader

precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D sampler;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main( void ) {
  //gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 );

  // Read fragment color from texture
  // TODO [exercise 9]
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, vec2(v_texCoord.s, v_texCoord.t));
}

//Texture Vertex Shader

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 P;

void main() {
  gl_Position = P * V * M * vec4( a_position, 1.0 );
  v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}

   // Phong Vertex Shader

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;

// Pass color as attribute and forward it
// to the fragment shader
attribute vec4 a_color;

uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 N; // normal matrix

varying vec3 v_normal;

// Pass the vertex position in view space
// to the fragment shader
// TODO [exercise 9]

varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec4 v_color;

void main() {
  gl_Position = P * V * M * vec4( a_position, 1.0 );

  // Pass the color and transformed vertex position through
   v_position = gl_Position;
   v_color = a_color;

  v_normal = (N * vec4(a_normal, 0)).xyz;
}

//Phong Fragment Shader
//precision mediump float;
// TODO [exercise 5]
//void main( void ) {
  //gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 );
  // TODO [exercise 5]
//}

// Wird mindestens einmal pro Pixel ausgefuehrt

precision mediump float;
// TODO [exercise 5]
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec4 v_position;
varying vec3 v_normal;

const vec3 lightPos = vec3(0.2,-1.0,-1.0);
const float shininess = 16.0;

const float k_a = 1.0;
const float k_d = 0.6;
const float k_s = 0.3;

// Farbe von Vertex shader durchreichen und Interpolieren
void main( void ) {
  // Rot, Gruen, Blau, Alpha
  //gl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0 );
  // TODO [exercise 5]
  vec3 vertPos = vec3(v_position) / v_position.w;
  vec3 N = normalize(v_normal);
  vec3 L = normalize(lightPos - vertPos);

  vec4 L_j = vec4(1,1,1,1);

  vec4 diffuse = L_j * max(dot(N, L), 0.0);

  vec3 R = reflect(-L, N);
  vec3 V = normalize(-vertPos);
  float specAngle = max(dot(R, V), 0.0);
  vec4 specular = L_j * pow(specAngle, shininess);

  vec4 color = vec4(k_a * v_color + k_d * diffuse + k_s * specular);
  gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>ICG-11 Animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container text-center">
    <h1>ICG Animation</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Implement a Rasteriser with WebGL using a Scenegraph.</p>
    <canvas id="rasteriser" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <script src="vector.js"></script>
    <script src="raster-texture-box.js"></script>
    <script src="matrix.js"></script>
    <script src="nodes.js"></script>
    <script src="rastervisitor.js"></script>
    <script src="shader.js"></script>
    <script src="animation-nodes.js"></script>
    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById("rasteriser");
      const gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

      // construct scene graph
      const sg = new GroupNode(Matrix.scaling(new Vector(0.2, 0.2, 0.2)));
      const gn1 = new GroupNode(Matrix.translation(new Vector(1, 1, 0)));
      sg.add(gn1);

      let gn2 = new GroupNode(Matrix.translation(new Vector(-.7, -0.4, .1)));
      sg.add(gn2);
      const cube = new TextureBoxNode(
        new Vector(-1, -1, -1, 1),
        new Vector(1, 1, 1, 1),
        'diffuse.png'
      );
      gn2.add(cube);

      // setup for rendering
      const setupVisitor = new RasterSetupVisitor(gl);
      setupVisitor.setup(sg);

      const visitor = new RasterVisitor(gl);

      let camera = {
        eye: new Vector(-.5, .5, -1, 1),
        center: new Vector(0, 0, 0, 1),
        up: new Vector(0, 1, 0, 0),
        fovy: 60,
        aspect: canvas.width / canvas.height,
        near: 0.1,
        far: 100
      };

      const phongShader = new Shader(gl,
        "phong-vertex-perspective-shader.glsl",
        "phong-fragment-shader.glsl"
      );
      visitor.shader = phongShader;
      const textureShader = new Shader(gl,
        "texture-vertex-perspective-shader.glsl",
        "texture-fragment-shader.glsl"
      );
      visitor.textureshader = textureShader;

      let animationNodes = [
        new RotationNode(gn2, new Vector(0, 0, 1))
      ];

      function simulate(deltaT) {
        for (animationNode of animationNodes) {
          animationNode.simulate(deltaT);
        }
      }

      let lastTimestamp = performance.now();

      function animate(timestamp) {
        simulate(timestamp - lastTimestamp);
        visitor.render(sg, camera);
        lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      }
      Promise.all(
        [textureShader.load(), phongShader.load()]
      ).then(x =>
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
      );

    </script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hey there I`m trying since a while now to add a second texture

[image]

to my cube and  do some bump mapping. But I am a progam beginner, so its kinda hard for me. All my maths for the matrix and vector are in the same named js.files. I also have to kinds of shaders, the texture and the phong shader. Now everyone says I have to calculate my normals, but how do I do that? And where?
Looking forward for your help!

Comment: I do not see any bump/normal mapping in your fragment shader. The idea is to get the normal from texture apply transformation on it and use that for the lighting computations.  You are just outputting texture as color. Take a look at this: [Normal mapping gone horribly wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541305/2521214) but it is C++/GLSL but the shaders should be similar. Also You need TBN (tangent,binormal,normal) matrix for each face (triangle) in order to be capable of converting the texture normal to real normal I do not see you passing it from vertex shade nor computing it on your own

Comment: start small first just add lighting and normals ... if working only then go for bump/normal mapping.

Answer (score 4):

With a normal map as in the question, [Bump mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_mapping) can be performed. At bump mapping the normal vector of a fragment is read from a normal map and used for the light calculations.
In general the incident light vector is transformed into texture space. This is the "orientation" of the normal map on the object (fragment). In order to set up a 3x3 orientation matrix that describes the orientation of the map, the tangent vector and the bi-tangent vector as well as the normal vector must be known. If there is no tangent vector and no bi-tangent vector, the vectors can be approximated by the partial derivative of the vertex position and the texture coordinate in the fragment shader.

So at least the texture coordinate and the normal vector attribute are required. In the fragment shader the calculations are done in world space respectively texture space. The vertex shader is straight forward:

```c
precision highp float;

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

varying vec3 w_pos;
varying vec3 w_nv;
varying vec2 o_uv;
    
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;

void main()
{   
    o_uv          = a_texCoord;
    w_nv          = normalize(mat3(M) * a_normal);
    vec4 worldPos = M * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    w_pos         = worldPos.xyz;
    gl_Position   = P * V * worldPos;
}
```

In the fragment shader, the normal vector is read from the normal map:

```c
vec3 mapN = normalize(texture2D(u_normal_map, o_uv.st).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0);
```

The light vector is transformed to texture space:

```c
vec3 L = tbn_inv * normalize(u_light_pos - w_pos);
```

With this vector the light calculations can be performed:

```c
float kd   = max(0.0, dot(mapN, L));
```

To calculate the matrix which transforms form world space to texture space, the partial derivative functions ([`dFdx`, `dFdy`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/dFdx.xhtml)) are required. This causes that the *"OES_standard_derivatives"* has to be enabled (or "webgl2" context):

```js
gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
var standard_derivatives = gl.getExtension("OES_standard_derivatives");
```

The algorithm to calculate the tangent vector and binormal vector is explained in another answer - [How to calculate Tangent and Binormal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255806/how-to-calculate-tangent-and-binormal/44901073#44901073).

Final fragment shader:

```c
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 w_pos;
varying vec3 w_nv;
varying vec2 o_uv;

uniform vec3 u_light_pos;
uniform sampler2D u_diffuse;
uniform sampler2D u_normal_map;

void main()
{
    vec3  N       = normalize(w_nv);
    vec3  dp1     = dFdx( w_pos );
    vec3  dp2     = dFdy( w_pos );
    vec2  duv1    = dFdx( o_uv );
    vec2  duv2    = dFdy( o_uv );
    vec3  dp2perp = cross(dp2, N);
    vec3  dp1perp = cross(N, dp1);
    vec3  T       = dp2perp * duv1.x + dp1perp * duv2.x;
    vec3  B       = dp2perp * duv1.y + dp1perp * duv2.y;
    float invmax  = inversesqrt(max(dot(T, T), dot(B, B)));
    mat3  tm      = mat3(T * invmax, B * invmax, N);
    mat3  tbn_inv = mat3(vec3(tm[0].x, tm[1].x, tm[2].x), vec3(tm[0].y, tm[1].y, tm[2].y), vec3(tm[0].z, tm[1].z, tm[2].z));

    vec3  L    = tbn_inv * normalize(u_light_pos - w_pos);
    vec3  mapN = normalize(texture2D(u_normal_map, o_uv.st).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0); 
    float kd   = max(0.0, dot(mapN, L));

    vec3 color     = texture2D(u_diffuse, o_uv.st).rgb;
    vec3 light_col = (0.0 + kd) * color.rgb;
    gl_FragColor   = vec4(clamp(light_col, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

And will produce bump mapping like this:

If the tangent vector is know the calculation of `tbn_inv` matrix can be simplified very much:

```c
mat3 tm = mat3(normalize(w_tv), normalize(cross(w_nv, w_tv)), normalize(w_nv));
mat3 tbn_inv = mat3(vec3(tm[0].x, tm[1].x, tm[2].x), vec3(tm[0].y, tm[1].y, tm[2].y), vec3(tm[0].z, tm[1].z, tm[2].z));
```

[image]

If you want [Parallax mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_mapping) like in this [Example](https://rabbid76.github.io/graphics-snippets/html/technique/parallax_mapping.html) then a displacement map is required, too.

[image]

The white areas on this map are pushed "into" the object. The algorithm is described in detail at  [LearnOpengl - Parallax Mapping](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Parallax-Mapping).
The idea is that each fragment is associated to a height of the displacement map. This can be imagined as a rectangular pillar standing on the fragment. The view ray is tracked until a displaced fragment is hit.

[image]

For a high performance algorithm samples are taken of the displacement texture. When a fragment is identified, then the corresponding fragment of the e normal map and the diffuse texture is read. This gives a 3 dimensional look of the geometry. Note this algorithm is bot able to handle silhouettes.

Final fragment shader with steep parallax mapping:

```c
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 w_pos;
varying vec3 w_nv;
varying vec2 o_uv;

uniform float u_height_scale;
uniform vec3 u_light_pos;
uniform vec3 u_view_pos;
uniform sampler2D u_diffuse;
uniform sampler2D u_normal_map;
uniform sampler2D u_displacement_map;

vec2 ParallaxMapping (vec2 texCoord, vec3 viewDir)
{
    float numLayers = 32.0 - 31.0 * abs(dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), viewDir));
    float layerDepth = 1.0 / numLayers;

    vec2 P = viewDir.xy / viewDir.z * u_height_scale;
    vec2 deltaTexCoords = P / numLayers;
    vec2 currentTexCoords = texCoord;

    float currentLayerDepth = 0.0;
    float currentDepthMapValue = texture2D(u_displacement_map, currentTexCoords).r;
    for (int i=0; i<32; ++ i)
    {
        if (currentLayerDepth >= currentDepthMapValue)
            break;
        currentTexCoords -= deltaTexCoords;
        currentDepthMapValue = texture2D(u_displacement_map, currentTexCoords).r;
        currentLayerDepth += layerDepth;
    }

    vec2 prevTexCoords = currentTexCoords + deltaTexCoords;
    float afterDepth = currentDepthMapValue - currentLayerDepth;
    float beforeDepth = texture2D(u_displacement_map, prevTexCoords).r - currentLayerDepth + layerDepth;

    float weight = afterDepth / (afterDepth - beforeDepth);
    return prevTexCoords * weight + currentTexCoords * (1.0 - weight);
}

void main()
{
    vec3  N       = normalize(w_nv);
    vec3  dp1     = dFdx( w_pos );
    vec3  dp2     = dFdy( w_pos );
    vec2  duv1    = dFdx( o_uv );
    vec2  duv2    = dFdy( o_uv );
    vec3  dp2perp = cross(dp2, N);
    vec3  dp1perp = cross(N, dp1);
    vec3  T       = dp2perp * duv1.x + dp1perp * duv2.x;
    vec3  B       = dp2perp * duv1.y + dp1perp * duv2.y;
    float invmax  = inversesqrt(max(dot(T, T), dot(B, B)));
    mat3  tm      = mat3(T * invmax, B * invmax, N);
    mat3  tbn_inv = mat3(vec3(tm[0].x, tm[1].x, tm[2].x), vec3(tm[0].y, tm[1].y, tm[2].y), vec3(tm[0].z, tm[1].z, tm[2].z));

    vec3 view_dir = tbn_inv * normalize(w_pos - u_view_pos);
    vec2 uv = ParallaxMapping(o_uv, view_dir);
    if (uv.x > 1.0 || uv.y > 1.0 || uv.x < 0.0 || uv.y < 0.0)
        discard;

    vec3  L    = tbn_inv * normalize(u_light_pos - w_pos);
    vec3  mapN = normalize(texture2D(u_normal_map, uv.st).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0); 
    float kd   = max(0.0, dot(mapN, L));

    vec3 color     = texture2D(u_diffuse, uv.st).rgb;
    vec3 light_col = (0.1 + kd) * color.rgb;
    gl_FragColor   = vec4(clamp(light_col, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0);
}
```

The result is much more impressive:

[image]

```js
(function loadscene() {

var gl, progDraw, vp_size;
var bufCube = {};
var diffuse_tex = 1;
var height_tex = 2;
var normal_tex = 3;

function render(deltaMS){

    var height_scale = 0.3 * document.getElementById("height").value / 100.0;
    
    // setup view projection and model
    vp_size = [canvas.width, canvas.height];
    camera.Update( vp_size );
    var prjMat = camera.Perspective();
    var viewMat = camera.LookAt();
    var modelMat = camera.AutoModelMatrix();
        
    gl.viewport( 0, 0, vp_size[0], vp_size[1] );
    gl.enable( gl.DEPTH_TEST );
    gl.clearColor( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
    gl.clear( gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
    
    gl.frontFace(gl.CCW)
    gl.cullFace(gl.BACK)
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE)

    // set up draw shader
    ShProg.Use( progDraw );
    ShProg.SetF3( progDraw, "u_view_pos", camera.pos )
    ShProg.SetF3( progDraw, "u_light_pos", [0.0, 5.0, 5.0] )
    ShProg.SetF1( progDraw, "u_height_scale", height_scale );
    ShProg.SetI1( progDraw, "u_diffuse", diffuse_tex );
    ShProg.SetI1( progDraw, "u_displacement_map", height_tex );
    ShProg.SetI1( progDraw, "u_normal_map", normal_tex );
    ShProg.SetM44( progDraw, "P", prjMat );
    ShProg.SetM44( progDraw, "V", viewMat );
    ShProg.SetM44( progDraw, "M", modelMat );
    
    // draw scene
    VertexBuffer.Draw( bufCube );

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function initScene() {

    canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas");
    gl = canvas.getContext( "experimental-webgl" );
    var standard_derivatives = gl.getExtension("OES_standard_derivatives");  // dFdx, dFdy
    if (!standard_derivatives)
       alert('no standard derivatives support (no dFdx, dFdy)');
    //gl = canvas.getContext( "webgl2" );
    if ( !gl )
    return null;
    
    progDraw = ShProg.Create( 
    [ { source : "draw-shader-vs", stage : gl.VERTEX_SHADER },
        { source : "draw-shader-fs", stage : gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER }
    ] );
    if ( !progDraw.progObj )
        return null;
    progDraw.inPos = ShProg.AttrI( progDraw, "a_position" );
    progDraw.inNV  = ShProg.AttrI( progDraw, "a_normal" );
    progDraw.inUV  = ShProg.AttrI( progDraw, "a_texCoord" );
    
    // create cube
    let Pos = [ -1,-1,1,  1,-1,1,  1,1,1, -1,1,1, -1,-1,-1,  1,-1,-1,  1,1,-1, -1,1,-1 ];
    let Col = [ 1,0,0, 1,0.5,0, 1,0,1, 1,1,0, 0,1,0, 0, 0, 1 ];
    let NV = [ 0,0,1, 1,0,0, 0,0,-1, -1,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,-1,0 ];
    let TV = [ 1,0,0, 0,0,-1, -1,0,0, 0,0,1, 1,0,0, -1,0,0 ];
    var cubeHlpInx = [ 0,1,2,3, 1,5,6,2, 5,4,7,6, 4,0,3,7, 3,2,6,7, 1,0,4,5 ];  
    var cubePosData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; ++ i ) cubePosData.push(Pos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3], Pos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+1], Pos[cubeHlpInx[i]*3+2] );
    var cubeNVData = [];
    for ( var i1 = 0; i1 < 6; ++ i1 ) {
        for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 ) cubeNVData.push(NV[i1*3], NV[i1*3+1], NV[i1*3+2]);
    }
    var cubeTVData = [];
    for ( var i1 = 0; i1 < 6; ++ i1 ) {
        for ( i2 = 0; i2 < 4; ++ i2 ) cubeTVData.push(TV[i1*3], TV[i1*3+1], TV[i1*3+2]);
    }
    var cubeColData = [];
    for ( var is = 0; is < 6; ++ is ) {
        for ( var ip = 0; ip < 4; ++ ip ) cubeColData.push(Col[is*3], Col[is*3+1], Col[is*3+2]); 
    }
    var cubeTexData = []
    for ( var i = 0; i < 6; ++ i ) cubeTexData.push( 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1 );
    var cubeInxData = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < cubeHlpInx.length; i += 4 ) cubeInxData.push( i, i+1, i+2, i, i+2, i+3 ); 
    bufCube = VertexBuffer.Create(
    [ { data : cubePosData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inPos },
    { data : cubeNVData,  attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inNV },
    //{ data : cubeTVData,  attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inTV },
    { data : cubeTexData, attrSize : 2, attrLoc : progDraw.inUV },
    //{ data : cubeColData, attrSize : 3, attrLoc : progDraw.inCol },
    ],
    cubeInxData, gl.TRIANGLES );

    Texture.LoadTexture2D( diffuse_tex, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/woodtiles.jpg" );
    Texture.LoadTexture2D( height_tex, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/toy_box_disp.png" );
    Texture.LoadTexture2D( normal_tex, "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/toy_box_normal.png" );
    
    camera = new Camera( [0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], 90, vp_size, 0.5, 100 );

    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

function resize() {
    //vp_size = [gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight];
    vp_size = [window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight];
    //vp_size = [256, 256];
    canvas.width = vp_size[0];
    canvas.height = vp_size[1];
}

function Fract( val ) { 
    return val - Math.trunc( val );
}
function CalcAng( deltaTime, interval ) {
    return Fract( deltaTime / (1000*interval) ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
}
function CalcMove( deltaTime, interval, range ) {
    var pos = self.Fract( deltaTime / (1000*interval) ) * 2.0
    var pos = pos < 1.0 ? pos : (2.0-pos)
    return range[0] + (range[1] - range[0]) * pos;
}    

function IdentM44() { 
    return [ 1, 0, 0, 0,    0, 1, 0, 0,    0, 0, 1, 0,    0, 0, 0, 1 ];
};

function RotateAxis(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var aMap = [ [1, 2], [2, 0], [0, 1] ];
    var a0 = aMap[axis][0], a1 = aMap[axis][1]; 
    var sinAng = Math.sin(angRad), cosAng = Math.cos(angRad);
    var matB = matA.slice(0);
    for ( var i = 0; i < 3; ++ i ) {
        matB[a0*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * cosAng + matA[a1*4+i] * sinAng;
        matB[a1*4+i] = matA[a0*4+i] * -sinAng + matA[a1*4+i] * cosAng;
    }
    return matB;
}

function Rotate(matA, angRad, axis) {
    var s = Math.sin(angRad), c = Math.cos(angRad);
    var x = axis[0], y = axis[1], z = axis[2]; 
    matB = [
        x*x*(1-c)+c,   x*y*(1-c)-z*s, x*z*(1-c)+y*s, 0,
        y*x*(1-c)+z*s, y*y*(1-c)+c,   y*z*(1-c)-x*s, 0,
        z*x*(1-c)-y*s, z*y*(1-c)+x*s, z*z*(1-c)+c,   0,
        0,             0,             0,             1 ];
    return Multiply(matA, matB);
}    

function Multiply(matA, matB) {
    matC = IdentM44();
    for (var i0=0; i0<4; ++i0 )
        for (var i1=0; i1<4; ++i1 )
            matC[i0*4+i1] = matB[i0*4+0] * matA[0*4+i1] + matB[i0*4+1] * matA[1*4+i1] + matB[i0*4+2] * matA[2*4+i1] + matB[i0*4+3] * matA[3*4+i1]  
    return matC;
}

function Cross( a, b ) { return [ a[1] * b[2] - a[2] * b[1], a[2] * b[0] - a[0] * b[2], a[0] * b[1] - a[1] * b[0], 0.0 ]; }
function Dot( a, b ) { return a[0]*b[0] + a[1]*b[1] + a[2]*b[2]; }
function Normalize( v ) {
    var len = Math.sqrt( v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2] );
    return [ v[0] / len, v[1] / len, v[2] / len ];
}

Camera = function( pos, target, up, fov_y, vp, near, far ) {
this.Time = function() { return Date.now(); }
this.pos = pos;
this.target = target;
this.up = up;
this.fov_y = fov_y;
this.vp = vp;
this.near = near;
this.far = far;
this.orbit_mat = this.current_orbit_mat = this.model_mat = this.current_model_mat = IdentM44();
this.mouse_drag = this.auto_spin = false;
this.auto_rotate = true;
this.mouse_start = [0, 0];
this.mouse_drag_axis = [0, 0, 0];
this.mouse_drag_angle = 0;
this.mouse_drag_time = 0;
this.drag_start_T = this.rotate_start_T = this.Time();
this.Ortho = function() {
    var fn = this.far + this.near;
    var f_n = this.far - this.near;
    var w = this.vp[0];
    var h = this.vp[1];
    return [
        2/w, 0,   0,       0,
        0,   2/h, 0,       0,
        0,   0,   -2/f_n,  0,
        0,   0,   -fn/f_n, 1 ];
};  
this.Perspective = function() {
    var n = this.near;
    var f = this.far;
    var fn = f + n;
    var f_n = f - n;
    var r = this.vp[0] / this.vp[1];
    var t = 1 / Math.tan( Math.PI * this.fov_y / 360 );
    return [
        t/r, 0, 0,          0,
        0,   t, 0,          0,
        0,   0, -fn/f_n,   -1,
        0,   0, -2*f*n/f_n, 0 ];
}; 
this.LookAt = function() {
    var mz = Normalize( [ this.pos[0]-this.target[0], this.pos[1]-this.target[1], this.pos[2]-this.target[2] ] );
    var mx = Normalize( Cross( this.up, mz ) );
    var my = Normalize( Cross( mz, mx ) );
    var tx = Dot( mx, this.pos );
    var ty = Dot( my, this.pos );
    var tz = Dot( [-mz[0], -mz[1], -mz[2]], this.pos ); 
    return [mx[0], my[0], mz[0], 0, mx[1], my[1], mz[1], 0, mx[2], my[2], mz[2], 0, tx, ty, tz, 1]; 
}; 
this.AutoModelMatrix = function() {
    return this.auto_rotate ? Multiply(this.current_model_mat, this.model_mat) : this.model_mat;
};
this.Update = function(vp_size) {
    if (vp_size)
        this.vp = vp_size;
    var current_T = this.Time();
    this.current_model_mat = IdentM44()
    var auto_angle_x = Fract( (current_T - this.rotate_start_T) / 13000.0 ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
    var auto_angle_y = Fract( (current_T - this.rotate_start_T) / 17000.0 ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
    this.current_model_mat = RotateAxis( this.current_model_mat, auto_angle_x, 0 );
    this.current_model_mat = RotateAxis( this.current_model_mat, auto_angle_y, 1 );
};
}

var Texture = {};
Texture.HandleLoadedTexture2D = function( texture, flipY ) {
    gl.activeTexture( gl.TEXTURE0 + texture.unit );
    gl.bindTexture( gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture.obj );
    gl.pixelStorei( gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, flipY != undefined && flipY == true );
    gl.texImage2D( gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.REPEAT );
    gl.texParameteri( gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.REPEAT );
    return texture;
}
Texture.LoadTexture2D = function( unit, name ) {
    var texture = {};
    texture.obj = gl.createTexture();
    texture.unit = unit;
    texture.image = new Image();
    texture.image.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
    texture.image.onload = function () {
        Texture.HandleLoadedTexture2D( texture, false )
    }
    texture.image.src = name;
    return texture;
}

var ShProg = {
Create: function (shaderList) {
    var shaderObjs = [];
    for (var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderList.length; ++i_sh) {
        var shderObj = this.Compile(shaderList[i_sh].source, shaderList[i_sh].stage);
        if (shderObj) shaderObjs.push(shderObj);
    }
    var prog = {}
    prog.progObj = this.Link(shaderObjs)
    if (prog.progObj) {
        prog.attrInx = {};
        var noOfAttributes = gl.getProgramParameter(prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_ATTRIBUTES);
        for (var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfAttributes; ++i_n) {
            var name = gl.getActiveAttrib(prog.progObj, i_n).name;
            prog.attrInx[name] = gl.getAttribLocation(prog.progObj, name);
        }
        prog.uniLoc = {};
        var noOfUniforms = gl.getProgramParameter(prog.progObj, gl.ACTIVE_UNIFORMS);
        for (var i_n = 0; i_n < noOfUniforms; ++i_n) {
            var name = gl.getActiveUniform(prog.progObj, i_n).name;
            prog.uniLoc[name] = gl.getUniformLocation(prog.progObj, name);
        }
    }
    return prog;
},
AttrI: function (prog, name) { return prog.attrInx[name]; },
UniformL: function (prog, name) { return prog.uniLoc[name]; },
Use: function (prog) { gl.useProgram(prog.progObj); },
SetI1: function (prog, name, val) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1i(prog.uniLoc[name], val); },
SetF1: function (prog, name, val) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform1f(prog.uniLoc[name], val); },
SetF2: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform2fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetF3: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform3fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetF4: function (prog, name, arr) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniform4fv(prog.uniLoc[name], arr); },
SetM33: function (prog, name, mat) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix3fv(prog.uniLoc[name], false, mat); },
SetM44: function (prog, name, mat) { if (prog.uniLoc[name]) gl.uniformMatrix4fv(prog.uniLoc[name], false, mat); },
Compile: function (source, shaderStage) {
    var shaderScript = document.getElementById(source);
    if (shaderScript)
        source = shaderScript.text;
    var shaderObj = gl.createShader(shaderStage);
    gl.shaderSource(shaderObj, source);
    gl.compileShader(shaderObj);
    var status = gl.getShaderParameter(shaderObj, gl.COMPILE_STATUS);
    if (!status) alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shaderObj));
    return status ? shaderObj : null;
},
Link: function (shaderObjs) {
    var prog = gl.createProgram();
    for (var i_sh = 0; i_sh < shaderObjs.length; ++i_sh)
        gl.attachShader(prog, shaderObjs[i_sh]);
    gl.linkProgram(prog);
    status = gl.getProgramParameter(prog, gl.LINK_STATUS);
    if ( !status ) alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(prog));
    return status ? prog : null;
} };
  
var VertexBuffer = {
Create: function(attribs, indices, type) {
    var buffer = { buf: [], attr: [], inx: gl.createBuffer(), inxLen: indices.length, primitive_type: type ? type : gl.TRIANGLES };
    for (var i=0; i<attribs.length; ++i) {
        buffer.buf.push(gl.createBuffer());
        buffer.attr.push({ size : attribs[i].attrSize, loc : attribs[i].attrLoc });
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.buf[i]);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array( attribs[i].data ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer.inx);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array( indices ), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    return buffer;
},
Draw: function(bufObj) {
    for (var i=0; i<bufObj.buf.length; ++i) {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.buf[i]);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(bufObj.attr[i].loc, bufObj.attr[i].size, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray( bufObj.attr[i].loc);
    }
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufObj.inx);
    gl.drawElements(bufObj.primitive_type, bufObj.inxLen, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    for (var i=0; i<bufObj.buf.length; ++i)
       gl.disableVertexAttribArray(bufObj.attr[i].loc);
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
    gl.bindBuffer( gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, null );
} };
  
initScene();

})();
```

```css
html,body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden; }
#gui { position : absolute; top : 0; left : 0; }
```

```html
<script id="draw-shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
precision highp float;

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_normal;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

varying vec3 w_pos;
varying vec3 w_nv;
varying vec2 o_uv;
    
uniform mat4 P;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 M;

void main()
{   
    o_uv          = a_texCoord;
    w_nv          = normalize(mat3(M) * a_normal);
    vec4 worldPos = M * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    w_pos         = worldPos.xyz;
    gl_Position   = P * V * worldPos;
}
</script>
  
<script id="draw-shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 w_pos;
varying vec3 w_nv;
varying vec2 o_uv;

uniform float u_height_scale;
uniform vec3 u_light_pos;
uniform vec3 u_view_pos;
uniform sampler2D u_diffuse;
uniform sampler2D u_normal_map;
uniform sampler2D u_displacement_map;

vec2 ParallaxMapping (vec2 texCoord, vec3 viewDir)
{
    float numLayers = 32.0 - 31.0 * abs(dot(vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), viewDir));
    float layerDepth = 1.0 / numLayers;

    vec2 P = viewDir.xy / viewDir.z * u_height_scale;
    vec2 deltaTexCoords = P / numLayers;
    vec2 currentTexCoords = texCoord;

    float currentLayerDepth = 0.0;
    float currentDepthMapValue = texture2D(u_displacement_map, currentTexCoords).r;
    for (int i=0; i<32; ++ i)
    {
        if (currentLayerDepth >= currentDepthMapValue)
            break;
        currentTexCoords -= deltaTexCoords;
        currentDepthMapValue = texture2D(u_displacement_map, currentTexCoords).r;
        currentLayerDepth += layerDepth;
    }

    vec2 prevTexCoords = currentTexCoords + deltaTexCoords;
    float afterDepth = currentDepthMapValue - currentLayerDepth;
    float beforeDepth = texture2D(u_displacement_map, prevTexCoords).r - currentLayerDepth + layerDepth;

    float weight = afterDepth / (afterDepth - beforeDepth);
    return prevTexCoords * weight + currentTexCoords * (1.0 - weight);
}

void main()
{
    vec3  N       = normalize(w_nv);
    vec3  dp1     = dFdx( w_pos );
    vec3  dp2     = dFdy( w_pos );
    vec2  duv1    = dFdx( o_uv );
    vec2  duv2    = dFdy( o_uv );
    vec3  dp2perp = cross(dp2, N);
    vec3  dp1perp = cross(N, dp1);
    vec3  T       = dp2perp * duv1.x + dp1perp * duv2.x;
    vec3  B       = dp2perp * duv1.y + dp1perp * duv2.y;
    float invmax  = inversesqrt(max(dot(T, T), dot(B, B)));
    mat3  tm      = mat3(T * invmax, B * invmax, N);
    mat3  tbn_inv = mat3(vec3(tm[0].x, tm[1].x, tm[2].x), vec3(tm[0].y, tm[1].y, tm[2].y), vec3(tm[0].z, tm[1].z, tm[2].z));

    vec3 view_dir = tbn_inv * normalize(w_pos - u_view_pos);
    vec2 uv = ParallaxMapping(o_uv, view_dir);
    if (uv.x > 1.0 || uv.y > 1.0 || uv.x < 0.0 || uv.y < 0.0)
        discard;

    vec3  L    = tbn_inv * normalize(u_light_pos - w_pos);
    vec3  mapN = normalize(texture2D(u_normal_map, uv.st).xyz * 2.0 - 1.0); 
    float kd   = max(0.0, dot(mapN, L));

    vec3 color     = texture2D(u_diffuse, uv.st).rgb;
    vec3 light_col = (0.1 + kd) * color.rgb;
    gl_FragColor   = vec4(clamp(light_col, 0.0, 1.0), 1.0);
} 
</script>
  
<body>
  
<div>
  <form id="gui" name="inputs">
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td> <font color=#CCF>height scale</font> </td>
              <td> <input type="range" id="height" min="0" max="100" value="50"/></td>
          </tr>
      </table>
  </form>
</div>


<canvas id="canvas" style="border: none;" width="100%" height="100%"></canvas>
```